# Checking if $c$ is a limit point when calculating $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)$. Is it necessary?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I understand that $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)$ is defined if $c$ is a limit point of the domain of $f$. That said, if a question/proof requires you to calculate say for example,
$$\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$
given $f,g$ are functions which map from the open interval $(a,b)$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Do we need to make sure that $c$ is a limit point of $(a,b)\setminus A$, where $A=\{x\in (a,b) \ \vert \ g(x)=0\}$, before moving on to actually calculating the limit itself? I ask this because the books I've read never bother to mention this step.

Comment: If you come across a situation "in the wild", yes (though probably the answer is obviously that $c$ _is_ a limit point of the domain of $f/g$). If you're asking whether or not your instructor might deduct points if you don't, it's best to ask them. :)